# How to prove $\frac{1}{|x|^d}$ is not integrable in $\{{x\in \mathbb R^d:|x|>1}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I ran into this problem in the process of proving that a function is not integrable. I can solve this problem by integration in one dimension, but I don't know how I should start in higher dimensions.

Comment: JackT's answer assumes that $d$ is the dimension of the space. This looks right, but it would be nice if you made this explicit in your question.

Comment: The description has been revised, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using polar coordinates reduces this to 1D. If $\omega_n$ is the volume of the $n$-ball with radius 1 then \begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B_1} \frac{dx}{\vert x\vert^n} &= \int_1^\infty \int_{\partial B_\rho} \frac 1 {\rho^n} \, d \mathcal H^{n-1}_x \, d\rho \\
&= n \omega_n \int_1^\infty  \frac {d\rho} {\rho} =+\infty .   
\end{align*}